# Nested markup inside custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-customcontrol

I have created a custom control to implement a table we use all over the place. It has been working fine for a while and now I was asked to add a new column type that would allow any valid asp.net markup to be put in it and that markup will be rendred within that table column.

I created the following class:

```
    [PersistChildren(false), ParseChildren(true)]
    public class UserDefinedMarkupColumn : GridColumnBase
    {
        private Collection<WebControl> _innerMarkup = new Collection<WebControl>();

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public virtual Collection<WebControl> InnerMarkup { get { return _innerMarkup; } }

        public override System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell CreateCell(object dataSourceObject, GridColumnBase col, out CustomGridRow extraRow, Action<object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs> handler, bool isMobileLayout = false)
        {
            TableCell newCell = new TableCell();

            foreach (var ctrl in _innerMarkup)
            {
                newCell.Controls.Add(ctrl);
            }

            extraRow = null;
            return newCell;
        }
    }
```

and this markup for the column:

```
<CustomGrid:UserDefinedMarkupColumn ID="markup" HeaderText="Some Markup">
   <InnerMarkup>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
   </InnerMarkup>
</CustomGrid:UserDefinedMarkupColumn>
```

The problem is that when I hit `CreateCell` the `_innerMarkup` collection is always empty. I saw several samples using a `ControlsCollection` but the issue is that `GridColumnBase` does not inherit from `Control`, it creates a `TableCell` which does.

**EDIT:** I also tried adding a `PlaceHolder` control and using it's `ControlsCollection`, but it is empty as well.

```
private PlaceHolder _innerControl = new PlaceHolder();

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
public virtual ControlCollection InnerMarkup { get { return _innerControl.Controls; } }
```

Comment: Have you tried using Templates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610625/asp-net-itemplate-ways-of-declaring

Comment: @PhilipPittle - I tried using a template. The issue is that the `Column` class itself does not inherit from `Control` or `WebControl`. I think this is why nothing is actually rendred and the template remains null.

Comment: Before we dive into the code, run a Wireshark trace and tell us what he query strings look like on the postback. This will lead us to the next step...

Comment: @user1522548 - What postback? This does not even work on the initial `GET`.

Comment: Ok put a breakpoint at the foreach statement and tell us what's in _innerMarkup.

Comment: That's what I thought initially.  This line does nothing: private Collection<WebControl> _innerMarkup = new Collection<WebControl>(); Except new up a collection of type WebControl.  Webcontrol is a class type not an instance of something unless it's static.  So somewhere in the PGM you have to add a webcontrol to the colleciton.

Comment: @user1522548 - I am adding controls to it via the markup. The collection is the default property of the control and is populated in the markup. But the instances of the controls are never created by the framework.

Comment: But you just told us the value is NULL... I don't understand.

Comment: @user1522548 - I am adding controls via the markup, but the instances of the controls are not created and the collection is empty.